# Choose Random Hash from Method Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I might be going a little out there with this one.

I'm using Cucumber Capybara with Ruby and I would like to create some hashes of specific data, then get my test to choose one of those hashes at random.  Can this be done?

My method containing hashes:

```
def random_vehicles


a1 = {:vrm => 'A1',
      :id => '11111111111',
      :post_code => 'AA11AA'
  }

b1 = {:vrm => 'B1',
      :id => '22222222222',
      :post_code => 'BB11BB'
  }

end
```

How can I randomly choose one of the two hashes within that method? Such as:

```
sample = random_vehicles.sample   # This doesn't work
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to choose between random data in your test?  This is a valid question without knowing that, but I am very curious, since random behavior in tests is usually something we avoid, not seek.

Comment: All I wanted was to input any valid data to just get to me a certain point in the webpage to start my tests, without hardcoding specific records into the Gherkin steps.  I thought I'd attempt to make it a little dynamic so more than one record is being entered. So I would use, Given I am logged in, Then I can start testing this page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could modify the method to make your initial `random_vehicles.sample` to work:

```
def random_vehicles
  [
    {:vrm => 'A1',
      :id => '11111111111',
      :post_code => 'AA11AA'
    },
    {:vrm => 'B1',
      :id => '22222222222',
      :post_code => 'BB11BB'
    }
  ]
end

random_vehicles.sample
#=> {:vrm=>"B1", :id=>"22222222222", :post_code=>"BB11BB"}
random_vehicles.sample
#=> {:vrm=>"A1", :id=>"11111111111", :post_code=>"AA11AA"}
```

Note that method name is important: it depends on what you actually want the method to return. In this case the method name is `sample_vehicles` (plural), so it feels natural, that it returns a collection of objects.

If you need it to already return a vehicle, than you should change the method and rename it:

```
def random_vehicle
  [
    {:vrm => 'A1',
      :id => '11111111111',
      :post_code => 'AA11AA'
    },
    {:vrm => 'B1',
      :id => '22222222222',
      :post_code => 'BB11BB'
    }
  ].sample
end

random_vehicle
#=> {:vrm=>"B1", :id=>"22222222222", :post_code=>"BB11BB"}
random_vehicle
#=> {:vrm=>"B1", :id=>"22222222222", :post_code=>"BB11BB"}
random_vehicle
#=> {:vrm=>"A1", :id=>"11111111111", :post_code=>"AA11AA"}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the naming convention makes more sense in this example

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
def random_vehicles
  a1 = {:vrm => 'A1',
      :id => '11111111111',
      :post_code => 'AA11AA'
  }

  b1 = {:vrm => 'B1',
      :id => '22222222222',
      :post_code => 'BB11BB'
  }

  [a1, b1]
end

vehicles = random_vehicles
p vehicles.sample
```

Comment: That's great for choosing data within the hashes.  As each hash contains 3 data items specific to a certain record, I'd need all 3 to pass validation.  So I'd need to randomly choose a1 or b1, then interact with the data inside.

Comment: The original way worked too, I'd mistyped something in my code in the IDE. Thanks for your answers

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)